# Authorizing dart package release redirects me to a localhost address

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter package. I had published dozens of versions of this package. Recently I transferred it to a publisher account. Now when I try to publish a new version using `dart pub publish` command, it says:

```
Pub needs your authorization to upload packages on your behalf.
In a web browser, go to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...
Then click "Allow access".
```

When I navigate to the URL and select a Google account, it redirects me to a local host port such as `https://localhost:60630/?code=...` which doesn't exist.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Localhost unreachable after sign-in" section at https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#localhost-unreachable-after-sign-in

I tried that and no luck on my windows. Then I copied the URL to chrome (my default browser is Edge), it works in chrome!

Comment: This doesn't work for me